# How do I change the density of x-ticks of a pandas time series plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot, time-series

I am trying to generate a smaller figure visualising a pandas time series. The automatically-generated x-ticks, however, do not adapt to the new size and result in overlapping ticks. I am wondering how can I adapt the frequency of the x-ticks? E.g. for this example:

```
figsize(4, 2)

num = 3000
X = linspace(0, 100, num=num)
dense_ts = pd.DataFrame(sin(X) + 0.1 * np.random.randn(num),
                        pd.date_range('2014-01-1', periods=num, freq='min'))

dense_ts.plot()
```

The figure that I get is:

[image: time series plot with overlapping x-ticks]

I am able to work around this problem using the Matplotlib date plotting, but it is not a very elegant solution - the code requires me to specify all the output formatting on a per-case basis.

```
figsize(4, 2)

from matplotlib import dates

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dense_ts.index.to_pydatetime(), dense_ts, 'b-')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.HourLocator(byhour=range(24),
                                           interval=12))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%m'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.WeekdayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n\n%a\n%Y'))

plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib date solution]

I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this issue using the pandas `plotting` module or maybe by setting some `axes` object properties? I tried playing with the `ax.freq` object, but couldn't really achieve anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a list of x axis values you want displayed in your dense_ts.plot()

```
dense_ts.plot(xticks=['10:01','22:01'...])
```

Another example for clarity

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3))
```

Plot without specifying xticks

```
df.plot(legend=False)
```

[image]

Plot with xticks argument

```
df.plot(xticks=[2,4,6,8],legend=False)
```

[image]

Comment: hm, that's interesting. Using this the xticks keyword argument I can sometimes control some input, but in an odd way - e.g. for `['00:00']` it prints out 06:00, 12:00, 18:00. For the 10, 22 case you mentioned, it loops forever.

Comment: I added another example

Comment: Yes, for integer indices it's a bit easier - you can also just call `locator_params(nbins=8)` to reduce the density. The problem is that this method doesn't work for Timestamp indices, where this function raises `AttributeError: TimeSeries_DateLocator instance has no attribute 'set_params'`.